# Show weekly data using MP Chart android java

Tags: android

I want to show a weekly data in Graph using MP Chart.
I have four types of exercises and want to show them in a graph like 
[image: expected result]

I am using the Bar Chart.
My Desired result is given in the picture 
[image: Expected Result]

XML

```html
  <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
                        android:id="@+id/chartWeeklyDistance"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_170sdp"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp" />
```

Java Code

```js
 private void updateWeeklyDistanceChart(){
        chartWeeklyDistance.setPinchZoom(false);
        chartWeeklyDistance.setDragEnabled(false);
        chartWeeklyDistance.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        chartWeeklyDistance.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        chartWeeklyDistance.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        chartWeeklyDistance.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
        chartWeeklyDistance.setTouchEnabled(false);
        chartWeeklyDistance.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);
        
        XAxis xAxis = chartWeeklyDistance.getXAxis();
//        xAxis.setTypeface(tfLight);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setLabelCount(7);
        xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new WeekDaysFormatter(chartWeeklyDistance));
        
        chartWeeklyDistance.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        
        float groupSpace = 0.08f;
        float barSpace = 0.03f; // x4 DataSet
        float barWidth = 0.2f; // x4 DataSet
        // (0.2 + 0.03) * 4 + 0.08 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"
        int progress = 7;
        int groupCount = progress;
        int startYear = 1980;
        int endYear = startYear + groupCount;

//        tvX.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d-%d", startYear, endYear));
//        tvY.setText(String.valueOf(seekBarY.getProgress()));

        ArrayList<BarEntry> values1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> values2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> values3 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> values4 = new ArrayList<>();

        float randomMultiplier = progress * 1000f;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            values1.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) (Math.random() * randomMultiplier)));
            values2.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) (Math.random() * randomMultiplier)));
            values3.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) (Math.random() * randomMultiplier)));
            values4.add(new BarEntry(i, (float) (Math.random() * randomMultiplier)));
        }

        BarDataSet set1, set2, set3, set4;

        if (chartWeeklyDistance.getData() != null && chartWeeklyDistance.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {

            set1 = (BarDataSet) chartWeeklyDistance.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
            set2 = (BarDataSet) chartWeeklyDistance.getData().getDataSetByIndex(1);
            set3 = (BarDataSet) chartWeeklyDistance.getData().getDataSetByIndex(2);
            set4 = (BarDataSet) chartWeeklyDistance.getData().getDataSetByIndex(3);

            set1.setValues(values1);
            set2.setValues(values2);
            set3.setValues(values3);
            set4.setValues(values4);
            chartWeeklyDistance.getData().notifyDataChanged();
            chartWeeklyDistance.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            // create 4 DataSets
            set1 = new BarDataSet(values1, "Company A");
            set1.setDrawValues(false);
            set1.setColor(Color.rgb(104, 241, 175));
            set2 = new BarDataSet(values2, "Company B");
            set2.setColor(Color.rgb(164, 228, 251));
            set2.setDrawValues(false);
            set3 = new BarDataSet(values3, "Company C");
            set3.setColor(Color.rgb(242, 247, 158));
            set3.setDrawValues(false);
            set4 = new BarDataSet(values4, "Company D");
            set4.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 102, 0));
            set4.setDrawValues(false);

            BarData data = new BarData(set1, set2, set3, set4);

//            data.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
//            data.setValueTypeface(tfLight);

            chartWeeklyDistance.setData(data);
        }

        // specify the width each bar should have
        chartWeeklyDistance.getBarData().setBarWidth(barWidth);

        // restrict the x-axis range
        chartWeeklyDistance.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(startYear);

        // barData.getGroupWith(...) is a helper that calculates the width each group needs based on the provided parameters
        chartWeeklyDistance.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(startYear + chartWeeklyDistance.getBarData().getGroupWidth(groupSpace, barSpace) * groupCount);
        chartWeeklyDistance.groupBars(startYear, groupSpace, barSpace);
        chartWeeklyDistance.animateY(1000);
        chartWeeklyDistance.invalidate();
    }
```

WeekDaysFormatter::

```
public class WeekDaysFormatter extends ValueFormatter {
private final String[] mDays = {"MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU",};

private final BarLineChartBase<?> chart;
private int count;

public WeekDaysFormatter(BarLineChartBase<?> chart) {
    this.chart = chart;
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
    Logger.log("WeekDaysFormatter", "value = "+value);
    String day = "";
    try {
        day = mDays[count];
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        count = 0;
        day = mDays[count];
    }

    count++;
    return day;
}
```

}

---

But I am getting [image: this]

Plus when I touch the graph the bottom days are shuffling.
But I want to draw a graph like [image: this]

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Are you talking about the bar graph color ?

Comment: I want to display week days on the bottom of Graph as given in the expected result picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZpot.png

Comment: your current result is showing week days on bottom of the graph

Comment: yes but these are not fixed that shuffle when I touch the graph. because of that ValueFormatter. I have also posted the code of formatter please check that also.
I want the days in this format. MO TU WE TH FRI SA SU.
But the order changes.

Answer (score 2):

```js
XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setLabelCount(6);
xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);

String[] daysOfTheWeek = {"MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR", "SA", "SU"};
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                Logger.log("WeeklyDistance", "value = " + ((int) value));
                if (((int) value) > -1 && ((int) value) < 7) {
                    return daysOfTheWeek[((int) value)];
                }
                return "";
            }
        });
        
chartWeeklyDistance.getXAxis().setAxisMinimum(0);
```